# Freezing a DataGridTextColumn in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I would like to freeze a DataGridTextColumn in WPF but it looks like there is not a property for that in that class specifically. However, looking at the source for the WPFToolkit, there is a IsFrozen in DataGridColumn which is the parent of DataGridBoundColumn, which is the parent of DataGridTextColumn. So...why isn't that property available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this property is not available because it's a read only. Since frozen columns are always the leftmost columns in display order you can use datagrid's FrozenColumnCount property to freeze whatever number of columns you need. You can set it up in xaml or chage it in you code. See documentation for more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount(VS.95).aspx)

Comment: Ahh, yes...of course. I don't know that this is what I wanted anyway. I'm wanting a datagrid to scroll right to left but keep a few columns where they are. This may be better served by having two datagrid's next to each other and have the right most datagrid in a scrollable panel.